# Как создать массив объектов с определенными свойствами на основе другого массива объектов?

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

Есть массив с каютами:

```
const cabins = [{
    adult: 1, // выбран 1 взрослый
    teenager: 1, // выбран 1 подросток
    babe: 1 // выбран 1 ребенок
  },
  {
    adult: 2, // выбрано 2 взрослых
    teenager: 0,
    babe: 1 // выбран 1 ребенок
  }
]
```

В котором было выбрано условно 2 каюты с пассажирами, при создании данного массива так же должен отдельно создаться еще один массив passengers = [] в котором будут присутствовать объекты (1 пассажир === 1 объект) с свойством WithSeat: 1 или WithSeat: 0 в зависимости от информации с backend который я получаю ниже:

```
const obj = {
  result: "1",
  types: [{
      ID: 1,
      Text: "Взрослый",
      WithSeat: 1 //с местом
    },
    {
      ID: 2,
      Text: "Подросток",
      WithSeat: 1 //с местом
    },
    {
      ID: 3,
      Text: "Ребенок",
      WithSeat: 0 //без места
    }
  ]
}
```

Вытаскиваю нужные мне WithSeat из массива бэкенда и создаю объект-определитель "с местом/без места" для дальнейшей работы:

```
const withSeat = {
  adult: 1,
  teenager: 1,
  babe: 0,
};
```

В конечном итоге я должен получить вот такую структуру массива объектов пассажиров:

```
const passengers = [{
    WithSeat: 1, // adult
  },
  {
    WithSeat: 1, // teenager
  },
  {
    WithSeat: 0, // babe
  },
  {
    WithSeat: 1, // adult
  },
  {
    WithSeat: 1, // adult
  },
  {
    WithSeat: 0, // babe
  },
]
```

По принципу работы это счетчик, в котором выбирается количество пассажиров и формируется массив cabins, приблизительный наглядный пример:
https://jsfiddle.net/xfh2csby/1/

Comment: в итоге, какой массив на основании каких ты должен получить? Какие входные данные, а какие выходные?

Comment: Должен сформироваться вот такой массив passengers на основе данных свойств массива cabins: `const passengers = [{
    WithSeat: 1, // adult
  },
  {
    WithSeat: 1, // teenager
  },
  {
    WithSeat: 0, // babe
  },
  {
    WithSeat: 1, // adult
  },
  {
    WithSeat: 1, // adult
  },
  {
    WithSeat: 0, // babe
  },
]` по факту например: const cabins = [{adult: 1},{babe; 1}], исходя из данных бэка нужно определить что adult === WithSeat: 1 а babe === WithSeat: 0 и за счет этой информации создать новый массив passengers = [{WithSeat: 1}, {WithSeat: 0}].

Comment: У тебя поля `adult`, `teenager`, `babe` никак не связаны с тем, что у тебя в `types` лежит

Comment: Извиняюсь не уточнил, из types я заранее вытащил свойства по такому принципу const adult = result.types[0]["WithSeat"]; и присвоил в объект withSeat как значение, withSeat = {adult: 1} чтобы можно было работать с значениями из бэка.

Comment: То есть на вход идет массив `cabinets` и объект `withSeat` ?

Comment: Да, сформировать passengers за счет cabins и withSeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Каждом элементу из массива `cabins` соответствует несколько элементов, по количеству полей. При этом каждом из полей может соответствовать несколько элементов по значению поля.

Для такого отображения удобно воспользоваться методами [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) и [`.flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

```js
const cabins = [{
    adult: 1, // выбран 1 взрослый
    teenager: 1, // выбран 1 подросток
    babe: 1 // выбран 1 ребенок
  },
  {
    adult: 2, // выбрано 2 взрослых
    teenager: 0,
    babe: 1 // выбран 1 ребенок
  }
];

const withSeat = {
  adult: 1,
  teenager: 1,
  babe: 0,
};

const result = cabins.flatMap(c => 
  Object.entries(c).flatMap(([kind, length]) => 
    Array.from({length}, () => ({
      WithSeat: withSeat[kind]
    }))));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, работает отлично) Еще подскажите пожалуйста как прочитать данную строку  `Array.from({length}, () => ({WithSeat: withSeat[kind]}))` ? Я понял, что с помощью flatMap-ов мы получаем свойства и значения массива cabins в виде примитивов, а дальше я не могу понять по какому принципу тут работает вызов функции.

Comment: @AndrewKoshman, `flatMap` отличается от `map` тем, что позволяет сделать плоский массив: `[[1],[2],[3]].flatMap(a=>a) -> [1,2,3]`. `Array.from({length}` - создает массив из `length` элементов, `() => ({WithSeat: withSeat[kind]})` - вызывается для каждого элемента и возвращает объект

Comment: Спасибо за объяснение, разобрался.